# NFS share not showing all directories

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nfs

I have 2 servers, Server A & Server B. I am trying to share a directory from Server A to Server B at the following locations. Both servers are running Ubuntu Server 18.04.3 LTS.

Server A: /home/administrator/apps/nginx/etc/letsencrypt

Server B: /etc/ssl/letsencrypt

Server A has the following structure for the share.

```
administrator@archon:~/apps/nginx/etc/letsencrypt$ ls -l
total 28
drwxr-xr-x 3 administrator administrator 4096 Aug  9 15:31 accounts
drwx------ 3 administrator administrator 4096 Aug  9 15:33 archive
drwxr-xr-x 2 administrator administrator 4096 Aug  9 15:32 csr
drwx------ 2 administrator administrator 4096 Aug  9 15:32 keys
drwx------ 3 administrator administrator 4096 Aug  9 15:33 live
drwxr-xr-x 2 administrator administrator 4096 Aug  9 15:33 renewal
drwxr-xr-x 5 administrator administrator 4096 Aug  9 15:31 renewal-hooks
```

Server B is only seeing this.

```
drwx------ 3 administrator administrator 4096 Aug  9 19:33 live
```

Server A: /etc/exports

```
/home/administrator/apps/nginx/etc/letsencrypt a_correct_subnet(ro,sync,no_subtree_check)
```

Server B: /etc/fstab

```
a_correct_host_ip:/home/administrator/apps/nginx/etc/letsencrypt       /etc/ssl/letsencrypt    nfs     auto,nofail,noatime,nolock,intr,tcp,actimeo=1800        0       0
```

Why aren't the rest of the directories showing up?
Both servers have a UID and GID of 1000 for 'administrator'.

Comment: Is the NFS share actually mounted? Add the output of `grep nfs /proc/mounts` on B